# Least dimension of Lie group acting transitively of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

I guess that the least possible dimension of a Lie group $G$ acting smoothly and transitively on a compact manifold $M$ is $\operatorname{dim}(M)$.

Is this correct and is there a ref?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This follows from Sard's theorem. If $G \times M \to M$ is smooth, then in particular $G \times \{pt\} \to M$ is smooth. If $\operatorname{dim} G < \operatorname{dim} M$, then Sard's theorem implies the image has measure zero, and in particular is not all of $M$.

Compactness is inessential here.

Comment: A lovely argument there!

Comment: While I think I've got what you mean, you could add a definition of $p, t, n$ and a bit more clarity.

Comment: pt means a point in $M$. I for some reason thought we had set $n = \dim M$ already. Sorry, fixed.

Comment: Hold up. Perhaps I'm confused. Sard's theorem implies the image of the singular points is a null set.

Comment: This shows that the least possible dimension of a Lie group $G$ acting smoothly and transitively on $M$ is **at least** the dimension of $M$.  But the question didn't say "at least".  I suspect that the actual least dimension of $G$ is sometimes bigger than the dimension of $M$.  What happens when $M$ is the two-dimensional sphere?

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I interpret the question differently than you did. As you suggest, no 2-dimensional Lie group can act transitively on $S^2$. (Because they are the same dimension, it would have to cover $S^2$, which is absurd because $S^2$ is not a Lie group.)

Comment: I meant to ask, show if the dimension of the group always greater than or equal to the dimension of the manifold. I.e. what mike tried to show.

Comment: @Benjamin: If $\dim G < \dim M$, then any point in the image of a smooth map $G \to M$ is a critical value by definition. Saying that the critical values have measure 0 is the same thing here as saying that the image has measure 0.

Comment: I see, that is slick. Thanks, it's very clear now.

Comment: @AndreasBlass There should be manifolds that don't permit any transitive action by a Lie group. I don't know an example off the top of my head.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: OK, here's a proof. A manifold with a transitive action by a Lie group $G$ is $G/\text{Stab}_x$, $x$ some point. The stabilizer is closed, hence a Lie subgroup. Both have trivial $\pi_2$, and as they're Lie groups and deformation retract onto their maximal compact subgroup, finitely generated abelian $\pi_1$. So if $M$ has a transitive action by $G$, we obtain an exact sequence $\pi_2(G) = 0 \to \pi_2(M) \to \pi_1(\text{Stab}_x)$. So pick a manifold $M$ with infinitely generated $\pi_2$, as is constructed for instance [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609456v3.pdf)...

Comment: in dimension as small as 4. (I don't know if there's a closed 3-fold with infinitely generated $\pi_2$.)

Comment: $\pi_2(S^2 \times S^1 \# S^2 \times S^1)$ is infinitely generated.